# getNetworkInterfaces + getInetAddresses not listing my machine ip address(cmd-> ipconfig)

Tags: java, networking

I am using the following code:

```
Enumeration e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
   NetworkInterface n = (NetworkInterface) e.nextElement();
   Enumeration ee = n.getInetAddresses();
   while (ee.hasMoreElements()){
       InetAddress i = (InetAddress) ee.nextElement();
       System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
   }
}
```

but is not listing my machine IP.
`cmd prompt -> ipconfig`